# Writing to file on the server in Meteor [1.0.0] (without losing the files every build)

Tags: javascript, file-io, meteor, fs, steam

The issue I've been having is that `fs.writeFile` writes to the `build` folder under `.meteor` and when rebuilt is lost.

The `Assets` api doesn't seem to allow for writes. All I'm looking to do is write some text to a file and load it up upon next startup.

Specific use case: Steam returns data for a `shaSentryfile` within their API that needs to be reused on subsequent requests, otherwise the authentication process is partially manual.

https://github.com/RJacksonm1/node-dota2
https://github.com/RJacksonm1/node-dota2/blob/master/test/index.js#L151

I've thought about using some external storage service like S3, but this is such a simple scenario--it's only the one file--but i'd like to understand how files like this should be managed in Meteor.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend writing files somewhere outside of your project's directory. This avoids any potential file location and reload issues.

If the file doesn't need to survive a restart, I'd recommend using your system's temp directory like so:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
var os = Npm.require('os');
var path = Npm.require('path');

var file = path.join(os.tmpDir(), 'foo.txt');
```

And then you can use `readFileSync` and `writeFileSync` with `file`.

Alternatively, you could specify a path using an environment variable:

```
> OUTPUT_DIR="$HOME/output" meteor
```

Then you could modify the above code to:

```
var file = path.join(process.env.OUTPUT_DIR, 'foo.txt');
```